# Открытие статьи из базы данных mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести открытие статьи на страницу, на главную страницу вывести получилось, как превью статьи вывел, не получается сделать чтобы при клике открывалась сама статья

-----------код из article (вывод самой статьи)-----------

```
<?php 
$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = 
" . (int) $_GET['id']); 
if( mysqli_num_rows($article) >= 0 ) 
{ 
?> 
<h1>Статья не найдена</h1> 
<?php 
} else 
{ 
$art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article); 
?>
СТАТЬЯ

<?php 
} 
?>
```

-----------код из index (страница главная, с превью статей) -----------

```
<?php 
$articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 
`categorie_id` = 3 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4"); 

while ($art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles) ) 
{ 
?>

СТАТЬЯ

<?php 
} 
?>
```

----------------ссылка по которой вывожу открытие статьи из index.php--------------

```
<a itemprop="url" class="product-image" href="/article.php?id=<?php echo 
$art['id']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не верное условие mysqli_num_rows($article)>=0. Знак > лишний

Comment: выдает ошибку на эту строку потом

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in D:\wordpress\openserver\OpenServer\domains\app\article.php on line 84

Comment: у вас лежит openserver в папке wordpress?)

Comment: @АлексейСоколов Вот так: mysqli_num_rows($article) == 0 или mysqli_num_rows($article) === 0

Comment: ТЫ ГЕНИЙ!!!!! СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕЕЕ))))))

Comment: Я сам его только начал изучать)

Comment: понял, но все равно спасибо огромное, очень выручил )